# How do I set the prefix in node-soap?

Tags: node-soap

Specifically does anyone know how I change the namespace from `<soap:Header>` to `<soapenv:Header>` and similarly attributes to something like `soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"` ?

My code currently looks something like this:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const url = 'https://staging.identitymanagement.lexisnexis.com/identity-proofing/services/identityProofingServiceWS/v2?wsdl';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
  client.setSecurity(new soap.WSSecurity('username', 'password', { 'mustUnderstand': 1}));
  client.invokeIdentityService({ 'workFlow': 'SOME_FLOW' }, (err, result, raw, soapHeader) => {
    console.log('Error======================');
    console.log(err);
    console.log('Result=============================');
    console.log(result);
    console.log('raw==============================');
    console.log(raw);
    console.log('soapHeader', soapHeader);
  });
});
```

It produces XML that looks something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat" xmlns:tns="http://ws.identityproofing.idm.risk.lexisnexis.com/" xmlns:survey="http://ns.lexisnexis.com/survey/1.0" xmlns:identity="http://ns.lexisnexis.com/identity-proofing/1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://ns.lexisnexis.com/identity-proofing/1.0">
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-2017-03-04T01:58:02Z">
        <wsu:Created>2017-03-04T01:58:02Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-03-04T02:08:02Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-2017-03-04T01:58:02Z">
    <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
    <wsu:Created>2017-03-04T01:58:02Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <tns:invokeIdentityService xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns3="http://sillypets.com/xsd">
    <workFlow>SOME_FLOW</workFlow>
</tns:invokeIdentityService>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

try it

```
let options = {envelopeKey: 'soapenv'};

soap.createClient(url,options, function(err, client) {
 ...
}
```